# Is Sanskrit the oldest language? Is it older than Pali?

Tags: sanskrit, language

Hindu texts are written in Sanskrit, were Hindu texts written before Pali texts?

Comment: Pali was the language that was spoken at the time of Buddha. Sanskrit was no longer used by people at that time, it was already only being used by brahmins as the vedas were in Sanskrit. Some of Buddha's followers wanted to put Buddha's words in Sanskrit as they were sacred, but Buddha wanted his words kept in Pali so that all people could understand them.

Comment: It means Sanskrit is older than Pali. Is there any reference or proof for it ?

Comment: wonder how a language specific question is on-topic here?

Comment: I think because both, Sanskrit and Pali are related to Hinduism.

Comment: Pali is related to Buddhism, not Hinduism. Question as such is off topic.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani: You should provide references that Sanskrit was for ruling class or edit your question. (There is enough evidence that Sanskrit was used my the masses)

Comment: @AmitSaxena Yes, I know Sanskrit was most popular but I have read at many places that at time of Buddha it was attributed to only ruling cast. Please check this article: http://www.baiae.org/great-people/buddha/life-of-buddha/103-how-brahmins-killed-buddhism-in-india.html

Comment: @AmitSaxena And also please provide some evidences (authentic) that Sanskrit was used by masses at the time of Pali.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani: Sure, Bibek Debroy mentioned that he has a copy of a text called the ChoryaShastra (a 'manual for thieves') which is very recently indexed by NAMAMI, a manuscript indexing initiative started by the govt. few years back. This clearly shows that Sanskrit was used by all classes of people. It is not avialable in public domain as of yet.
Also, the link you shared nowhere says that Sanskrit was used by the ruling class unless you categorise Brahmins as such, which shows a complete lack of understanding of the varna system.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani: Btw, the onus of providing references lies with you as you have asked the question. ;)

Comment: And yes I have given the wrong reference. Actually some of my facebook friends who called themselves research scholars used to write it every time. But I cannot give direct link of it. If you wish I can provide the whole paragraph. Sorry for that.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani: In that case, I recommend that you keep your question limited to which is the oldest language. :)

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani: This provides the reference to the oldest Pali text written in 5th century AD: http://www.dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?t=6033 
Definitely, Sanskrit is older, as Sanskrit texts were written way back: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Hindu_texts
I hope this answers your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The oldest surviving Buddhist texts in the *Pali* language come from
>   the relic chamber of a *Buddhist* stupa at *Sri Ksetra*. They consist
>   of a twenty-leaf manuscript of solid gold and a large gilded reliquary
>   of silver. A new and exhaustive palaeographic study of these
>   inscriptions shows that they date from the *mid-fifth to mid-sixth
>   century AD*.

This link provides multiple reference to support this claim : http://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?t=6033

The *Rig Veda*, a *Sanskrit* text was written around *1500 BC*. Although, it is said that there was an oral tradition spreading it for a very long time.
Hence, ***Sanskrit is older***, as Sanskrit texts were written way back. This link provides the dates when the *Sanskrit texts* were written including *Rig Veda*:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Hindu_texts

Comment: Rig Veda was not written in 1500 B.C. Let's not propagate Western Indologist nonsense. Rig Veda was compiled (not created) by Ved Vyasa at beginning of Kali Yuga in 3102 B.C

Answer (score 3):

[Vedic Sanskrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_Sanskrit) is much older than Pali texts. The Rig Veda was composed around 1500 - 1100 BCE, while the Buddhist text [Tripitaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripi%E1%B9%ADaka) was composed between 500 - 1 BCE. Vedic sages are also referenced in the Tripitaka (see [Majjhima Nikaya 95](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn95)). Interestingly, MN95 mentions three Vedas and not four. This proves that the Vedas are older than the Tripitaka. See [Timeline of Hindu texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Hindu_texts).

However, [Classical Sanskrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit#Classical_Sanskrit) was standardized by the grammarian [Panini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81%E1%B9%87ini) around the same period as the life of [Gautama Buddha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Buddha). The Bhagavad Gita was composed in Classical Sanskrit (to my understanding) and is dated 400 BCE - 300 CE. The Bhagavad Gita is therefore not older than the oldest composition of the Tripitaka.

Interestingly, Gautama Buddha did not speak Pali. He most likely spoke [Magadhi Prakrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magadhi_Prakrit), which was the main language of the Kingdom of [Magadha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magadha), where the Buddha spent most of his life in. The Buddha taught the people around him in their own language. Magadhi Prakrit basically means the Prakrit dialect spoken in Magadha. The [Edicts of Asoka](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~malaiya/ashoka.html) were also written in Magadhi Prakrit in the Brahmi and Kharosthi scripts.

Jain texts were written in [Ardhamagadhi Prakrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ardhamagadhi_Prakrit), which is also a related language. Jainism founder Mahavira lived around the same time as the Buddha, although the two never met. Mahavira is referenced in the Tripitaka as Nigantha Nataputta and Jains are referenced as Niganthas (see [Majjhima Nikaya 101](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn101)).

According to [Bhikkhu Bodhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhikkhu_Bodhi) (a leading Tripitaka scholar and translator) below, the [Pali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pali) language is a hybrid construction comprising several third century BCE Prakrit dialects and subjected to a partial process of Sanskritization. Therefore, Pali is definitely younger than Sanskrit and the Prakrits. Modern Magahi or Magadhi, Magadhi Prakrit, Ardhamagadhi Prakrit and Pali are all closely related languages.

> Scholars regard this language (Pali) as a hybrid showing features of several
>   Prakrit dialects used around the third century BCE, subjected to a
>   partial process of Sanskritization. While the language is not
>   identical to what Buddha himself would have spoken, it belongs to the
>   same broad language family as those he might have used and originates
>   from the same conceptual matrix. This language thus reflects the
>   thought-world that the Buddha inherited from the wider Indian culture
>   into which he was born, so that its words capture the subtle nuances
>   of that thought-world.

Answer (score 1):

it is false that Sanskrit is known from 3000 b.c.  it may have existed back then, but we have no proof.  if Indus valley script is proven to be Sanskrit it does push Sanskrit way back into the past.  the earliest known Indo-Aryan is from the mitanni kingdom - around 1400 b.c.  that makes attested Hittite, Sumerian and Akkadian older.

unfortunately, linguists say that attested vedic sanskrit is "younger" than mitanni indo aryan the same way hindi is younger than sanskrit.  a given hindi text maybe older than a given sanskrit text - but hindi as a whole is younger.  there ia word "priyamazda" in mitanni which is "priyamedha" in sanskrit and linguists say the Sanskrit form descended from the mitanni form.  there a few other examples that makes rig veda younger than Mitanni.

the mitanni data is very damning for out-of-india theories - but perhaps arguments may still be found to prove sanskrit originated from India.

Comment: There is no text from hittite-akkadian surviving so you can't research between two languages from just some inscriptions of those Hittite kingdoms, on the other hand a 4000 year old Vishnu idol has been found in Vietnam.

Comment: thats just the fantasy of graham hancock.  it is from 6 7 a.d. @anubhav jha

Comment: If we don't have proof that Sanskrit was not present back 300BC so does your answer doesn't provide any proof or any source. Also you are not answering my question.

Comment: You should cite some sources.

Answer (score -1):

According to researchers/archaeologists Sanskrit dating back to 3000 BC. and pali seem to have existed after sanskrit about 5-1 BCE ..

Comment: add some references

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate your answer please, else I need to convert your answer into a comment.